# Through-walkable object with collision!

Tags: game-engine, physics

I wanted to make a nice game, but I am having a problem with water. I am trying to make a simple underwater shader and motion, but I have to make my water so the character can also walk through it. It also must have collision, so I can activate the properties. How can I make its physics work like that?

Comment: Could you specify why you need collisions?

Comment: I need collision to activate property which makes the plane(which makes underwater shader) visible. Also I need collision to play sounds when walking under water... And... To make player loose health when being too long inside of water...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the water detect collisions and not actually register any collisions by setting it to ghost.

[image: Ghost box]

Once that box is checked, anything that hits it detects the collision, but it physically treats it like a no-collision mesh. So, you can simply have a logic setup similar to this one on your character.
[image: Logic bricks]

Comment: Yes... it really worked:)